# How To Sort A List Of Lists?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of lists that I would like to sort.

```
    foreach (var Row in Result)
    {
        foreach (var RowAll in Row.All)
        {
            DataObject.Add(new List<string>() { RowAll.Value1, RowAll.Value2, RowAll.Value3});
            break; 
        }
    }
```

Now I want to sort the parent list by each child list's Value2.
Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this via LINQ:

```
 // I'm assuming here that "LastCheckin" is defined as List<List<string>> or similar
 // ...

 var sorted = Data.LastCheckin.OrderBy(list => list[1]);
```

This will return an `IEnumerable<List<string>>` containing your "lists" sorted by the second value in the sub-list (Value2).

---

If you want to sort the list in place, you could use [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) instead:

```
 Data.LastCheckin.Sort( (a,b) => a[1].CompareTo(b[1]) );
```

If you need to specify, at runtime, ascending or decending, an easy way to handle this is:

```
 bool ascending = true; // Set to false for decending

 int mult = ascending ? 1 : -1;
 Data.LastCheckin.Sort( (a,b) => mult * a[1].CompareTo(b[1]) );
```

---

In order to handle more complex checking, you can split your lambda over multiple lines:

```
 bool ascending = true; // Set to false for decending
 string myDateFormat = GetDateFormat(); // Specify date format

 int mult = ascending ? 1 : -1;
 Data.LastCheckin.Sort( (aStr,bStr) => 
    {
        DateTime a, b;
        bool aSuccess = DateTime.TryParseExact(aStr[1], myDateFormat, DateTimeStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out a);
        bool bSuccess = DateTime.TryParseExact(bStr[1], myDateFormat, DateTimeStyles.None, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out b);

        int result;
        if (!aSuccess)
            result = bSuccess ? -1 : 0;
        else if (!bSuccess)
            result = 1;
        else
            result = a.CompareTo(b);

        return mult * result;

    });
```

This handles parser failures on a and b, and should put them at the end of the sort.

Comment: @Reed, thanks so much!
This bit in my code had bugged me for quite some time.

Comment: @Reed Copsey:
The value that I'm sorting is still in string format, so it is sorted in its string format rather than its date format.  How can I get this to work so it sorts by the value's date format?

Comment: @Soo: You'll need to convert the numbers to a Date first - ie: in the sort lambda, convert a & b to dates (using DateTime.Parse/TryParse), then compare the dates.

Comment: When I use DateTime.Parse, I get an error that reads: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime<br/>
This is what my dates look like:<br/>
2010-06-26 10:30:00.000

Comment: @Soo: You'll need to use DateTime.ParseExact and supply the format.

Comment: I'm using: DateTime.ParseExact(b[1], "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff}", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) and am getting the same error.  I think I'm doing everything correctly

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" <- I also tried this for the format parameter

Comment: @Soo: The latter should work, given the date you wrote earlier.  Can you put the latter, then show the exact string that's failing with it?

Comment: Ok, it looks like this is failing when there is no date value (this field can be "").  What can I add to skip the parse if it is ""?

Comment: You'll need to put custom logic in there - your "sort" lambda can be multiple lines, so just do a string.IsNullOrEmpty check and return -1/1 appropriately, and that'll put empty entries at the beginning or end.

Comment: Where would the string.IsNullOrEmpty be in this entire statement? I tried adding an if statement in there and things started to get error-y

Comment: @Soo: I added some code to show you one approach - see my latest edit above.

Comment: Reed, your code example doesn't work entirely, but I appreciate the effort.  I developed a much less elegant solution that I'm using instead. Also, if there is any way I can donate some reputation points to you, I'd like to be able to. 

Thanks again for all of the help!

Comment: @Soo: No problem.  The code i posted above should be close - but I wrote it on the cuff, not using VS - so I couldn't check it.  The basic concept should work, fine, however -

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this working:

```
listOfLists = listOfLists.OrderByDescending(a => a.Max(x => x.paramToSoryBy)).ToList();
```