# sort a list of a list of an object c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, sorting

I have a List of a List which contains an object.

```
List<List<Field>> records;
```

The Field object contains ID and Value.

I need to sort the top level List using attributes of the Field record.

The sort needs to say, for every record, select a list using an ID and then sort the parent by the value.

So if I had 2 records they would look like this:

```
  List[0] -> List [ID=1 Value="Hello", ID=2 Value="World"]
  List[1] -> List [ID=1 Value="It's", ID=2 Value="Me"]
```

using ID 1 would select the object in the child list and then sort the parent object.  If, for example, the ID was 2, the sort would swap the 0 and 1 items, as Me comes before World.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Sort A List Of Lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104042/how-to-sort-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925471/sorting-a-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of what you're looking for:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var structure = new List<List<string>>();
    structure.Add(new List<string>() {"Hello", "World"});
    structure.Add(new List<string>() {"It's", "Me"});

    SortBySubIndex(structure, 0);
    SortBySubIndex(structure, 1);
  }

  public static void SortBySubIndex(List<List<string>> obj, int index) 
  {
    obj = obj.OrderBy(list => list[index]).ToList();
    Console.WriteLine("INDEX: " + index);
    Console.WriteLine(obj[0][0]);
    Console.WriteLine(obj[1][0]);   
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's lovely.  Exactly what I was looking for.